# show a div based on between 2 calendar dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the below; which works fine, but I need to add variables that will be **between** 2 given dates for which the div will be shown.

```
var now = new Date();

var Date0 = new Date("November 12, 2015");

var Date1 = new Date("November 2, 2015"); // need to write between nov 2 - november 4

var Date2 = new Date("November 23, 2015");

var Date3 = new Date("November 22, 2015");


if(now > Date0) // today is after Christmas
{
     $('#date_0').show();
}

if(now > Date1) // today is after Christmas
{
     $('#date_1').show();
}

if(now > Date2) // today is after Christmas
{
     $('#date_2').show();
}

if(now > Date3) // today is after Christmas
{
     $('#date_3').show();
}
```

Comment: add one more date variable for 4 november and compare it with and condition in same if condition like `if(now > Date1 && now < Date4)`

Comment: We can not compare date objects like this, Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use && with both of date

```
if( new Date() < new Date("November 5, 2015")  && new Date() > new Date("November 1, 2015")) 
{
    console.log('in') //this will run form 2 nov to 4th nov
}
```